# Linux: Modifying the contents of /proc

Tags: linux, process, proc

I just found out that the /proc/$pid/mem file permissions are set to read/write for the owner. Why? Does that mean that the owner can write to process memory as it runs live?

(For the record, I haven't been able to open, print or write to the contents of that file for any process I launch yet, via various means).

So why is that some of the contents in /proc are actually modifiable? Is this deliberate, or something overlooked by the Linux devs?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Stay calm - procfs is secure :)  Here are a couple of good links: [Access the Linux kernel using /proc](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-proc/index.html) and http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html

Comment: And you cannot access `/proc/$pid/mem` from offset 0, you need to go to some meaningful offset (look into `/proc/$pid/maps` and use `lseek`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/proc is a directory-based view of information the kernel makes available to you.

Yes ... you can change it.

*see this example :*

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

you could use sysctl to configure these kernel items.